# Error al importar variable environment desde archivo .env usando dotenv

Tags: nodejs, express

Estoy desarrollando una función para verificar un token, me está funcionando correctamente, pero en Visual Code estoy viendo este fallo cuando compilo con tsc. No es bloqueante, pero me gustaría evitarlo. Alguien sabe a qué se refiere?

tengo en la raíz un archivo .env con la variable definida:

```
SECRETORPRIVATEKEY=palabrasecreta
```

[image: fallo visual code]

aquí el código entero:

```
    import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
    import dotenv from "dotenv";

    dotenv.config();

    const generarJWT = (id_usuario = "", email = "") => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const payload = { id_usuario, email };

        jwt.sign(
          payload,
          process.env.SECRETORPRIVATEKEY,
          {
            expiresIn: "4h",
          },
          (err, token) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              reject("imposible generar el token");
            } else {
              resolve(token);
            }
          }
        );
      });
    };

    export default generarJWT;
```

Answer (score 1):

yo uso siempre el modulo os, que viene con el python

```
import os
keys = os.getenv()
key["<Variable Name>"]
```

es muy simple

Comment: Podrias agregar una explicacion de lo que hace tu código por favor? Le vendria bien tanto a OP como a cualquier persona que vea tu respuesta en el futuro.

Comment: en este caso es nodeJs | Express, no uso Python

Comment: uff, perdona, ley mal

Answer (score 0):

Hay variables de entorno que no pueden ser ***undefined***, por lo que hay que indicarle un valor alternativo al llamarlas:

donde indicamos:

```
  process.env.SECRETORPRIVATEKEY
```

hay que añadir:

```
  process.env.SECRETORPRIVATEKEY || ""
```

cuando sean susceptibles de no poder ser undefined.